# Feature testing authentication with hidden property

Tags: php, laravel, testing

How can I to test user authentication? My test:

```
public function successLogin()
    {
        $user = User::factory()->create(['login' => '123']);
        $user->makeVisible(['password']);
        $this->post(route('login'), $user->toArray());
        $this->assertAuthenticated(); // not asserts
    }
```

I saw this decision

```
$this->User->makeVisible(['password']);
```

But what is this proterty? Model? It is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The decision was change post request of auth to attempt method:

```
public function successLogin()
{
    $user = User::factory()->create(['password' => \Hash::make('pass')]);
    \Auth::attempt(['login' => $user->login, 'password' => 'pass']);

    $this->assertAuthenticated();
}

public function failedLogin()
{
    User::factory()->create(['login' => 'username1', 'password' => \Hash::make('pass')]);
    \Auth::attempt(['login' => 'username2', 'password' => 'pass']);

    $this->assertGuest();
}
```